# Webdriver backed selenium java - how can I verify % within text on the page

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, assert

I'm running a test using webdriver backed selenium and java to verify an error message containing % this is causing the test to fail.

I have tried to use the UTF-8 code (`\u0025`) but this also fails.

Code:

```
assertTrue(
    Pattern.compile(
        "Please enter a password of between 6 and 20 characters. You may use lower or upper case letters a-z, numbers 0-9 and the following characters !\"£$%").
    matcher(
        selenium.getText(
            "//form[@id='registrationForm']/fieldset[3]/div/div[2]/div/p")).
    find());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a regex to match your strings (the $ means the end of a string/line)... if you really really want to use a regex I would recommend:

```
...
Pattern.compile(
    "Please enter a password of between 6 and 20 characters\\. You may use lower or upper case letters a-z, numbers 0-9 and the following characters !\"£\\$%").
matcher(
...
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
assertTrue(
    selenium.getText("//form[@id='registrationForm']/fieldset[3]/div/div[2]/div/p")
    .contains(
        "Please enter a password of between 6 and 20 characters. You may use lower or upper case letters a-z, numbers 0-9 and the following characters !\"£$%"
    ));
```